# Dynamic jQuery/JSON menus made static until logout

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I've got a list of news articles in < li > format that has been created dynamically using jQuery(.ajax) and JSON. When I receive the JSON data, I constructed the list items and appended them to the parent < ul >.

My problem is that if the user uses the back button and then re-enters the News area, the list gets fetched and appended again, giving me duplicate list items. Is there any way in jQuery to limit the .ajax request to one load? Or should I add all the news < li >'s to session/local storage?

Code:

```
$('#schoolnews').live("click", function(){
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
var schoolID = sessionStorage.getItem('schoolID');
var entityType = sessionStorage.getItem('entityType');
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.sycamoreeducation.com/mobile/JSON/getnewslist.php',
    data: {schoolID: 'schoolID', entityType: 'entityType'},
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data){
    //alert("Success in retreiving JSON News Data!");
    $.mobile.changePage('#news');
    $.each(data, function(index, value){
                var newslistitems = '<li class="newsitem" data-theme="c"><h3>' +value.Subject+ '</h3><p>Posted on: ' +value.Day+ '</p></li>';
            $('ul#newslist').append(newslistitems);
        });
    $('ul#newslist').listview('refresh');
    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
    },
    error: function(){
    alert('Error Message');
    }
}); //end login ajax call
}); //end school news click listener
```

Still very much a newbie when it comes to jQuery, so if you can spot any areas where I can improve, please don't hesitate to let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Try running empty() on the parent UL before the load of the data. This way whether the list has something in it or not its going to clear it all out then append whatever data. Its worth a shot

Comment: Thanks, @Chris! This is what I have been doing now (over a year later) and it's been working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use html()

Within the $.each change

```
var newslistitems ....
```

to

```
newslistitems +=
```

Then define newslistiems before the loop and after the loop add:

```
    $('ul#newslist').html(newslistitems);
```

This way each item gets added to the newslistitems variable and gets added to the ul#newslist at the end of the loop, html() will clear out any previous content within the ul#newslist replacing it with the contents of newslistitems variable.